# DirectX11 ReportLiveObjects Instantiation

Tags: c++, debugging, directx, layer, directx-11

[MSDN Page for ReportLiveObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/hh780352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I am unsure how to call the ReportLiveObjects method as the classes I am attempting to declare are abstract, or in the case of IDXGIDebug "undeclared" (I think I'm missing a header file?).

Here are the snippets.

```
    ID3D11Debug *debugDev = new ID3D11Debug();
    debugDev->ReportLiveDeviceObjects( D3D11_RLDO_DETAIL );
```

The above code tells me the class is abstract so I cannot create an object.

```
IDXGIDebug debugDev = new IDXGIDebug();
```

The above code tells me that IDXGIDebug is undeclared.

The header file "DXGI" has been included. Debug layer is on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course you can't create `ID3D11Debug` interface directly.

The first step is to create your `ID3D11Device` with `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` flag, like this:

```
creationFlags = 0;

#ifdef _DEBUG
        creationFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

D3D11CreateDevice(...);
```

Then you have to query `ID3D11Debug` interface from your device, like this:

```
m_d3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Debug), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_d3dDebug));
```

Two useful links about the D3D debug layer:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/jj200584(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/jj200584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx

Comment: The first one I've read but it doesn't really mention the debug device. The second was very informative but I still have simple reporting on some objects, which I can't fix because it seems I am missing a header file from my DX install. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a faux pas to reply to an 8 year old question, but the only answer doesn't actually answer the question about `IDXGIDebug`, so in case anyone else is looking for that answer:

You create the IDXGI interface with the `DXGIGetDebugInterface` or `DXGIGetDebugInterface1` function. `DXGIGetDebugInterface1` doesn't require a DLL so it should be easier to use:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dxgidebug.h>
...
IDXGIDebug * debugDev;
HRESULT hr = DXGIGetDebugInterface1(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&debugDev));
```

That should get the `IDXGIDebug` instance. Instead of calling `ReportLiveDeviceObjects` like with `ID3D11Debug`, you'll call `ReportLiveObjects`, which was referenced in the original post with the MSDN [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgidebug/nf-dxgidebug-idxgidebug-reportliveobjects?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and you can replace the parameters with whatever values you like (listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/dxgi-debug-id) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgidebug/ne-dxgidebug-dxgi_debug_rlo_flags)):

```
hr = debugDev->ReportLiveObjects(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, DXGI_DEBUG_RLO_ALL);
```