# How to get debug interface for directx 11 in C

Tags: c, graphics, directx, directx-11, c99

Trying to follow this example:

[DirectX11 ReportLiveObjects Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814230/directx11-reportliveobjects-instantiation)

I'm trying to get a debug interface setup using C99 with directx11. I've already defined COBJMACROS and CINTERFACE in order to use directx c api and currently have a triangle rendering on my screen. In order to get dxgi debug stuff setup I've tried:

```
IDXGIDebug1* debug = { 0 };
DXGIGetDebugInterface(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&debug));
IDXGIDebug1_ReportLiveObjects(debug, DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, DXGI_DEBUG_RLO_ALL);
```

but get errors that 'IID_PPV_ARGS' is not defined and I'm sure this is because I'm using the C interface and this is specific to c++. I've also tried:

```
IDXGIDebug1* debug = { 0 };         
ID3D11Device_QueryInterface(device, &IID_IDXGIDebug1, (void**)(&debug));        
IDXGIDebug1_ReportLiveObjects(debug, DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, DXGI_DEBUG_RLO_ALL);
```

But 'debug' variable isn't getting filled. Not sure what the equivalent C calls are for DXGI debug interface.

Comment: `IDXGIDebug1* debug = { 0 };` -- I always wonder if people realize that that 0 they keep using isn't the fill value for whatever object they're initializing.

Comment: Your definition of DXGIGetDebugInterface seems incorrect (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgidebug/nf-dxgidebug-dxgigetdebuginterface) It should only have two parameters riid and ppDebug which are covered by IID_PPV_ARGS(&debug). What's this 0 as first argument?

Comment: Oh, I was just following the example from the other stack overflow post. I changed it to `DXGIGetDebugInterface(&IID_IDXGIDebug1, IID_PPV_ARGS(&debug));` but still get the error concerning the IID_PPV_ARGS.

Answer (score -1):

After some diggin I found what I was looking for. The c function equilavent 'DXGIGetDebugInterface1' is located in the dxgi1_3.h header file and I was only including the dxgidebug.h header. Also, need to link to dxgi.lib. Final code is:

```
IDXGIDebug1* debug = { 0 };
DXGIGetDebugInterface1(0, &IID_IDXGIDebug1, (void**)(&debug));
IDXGIDebug1_ReportLiveObjects(debug, DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, DXGI_DEBUG_RLO_ALL);
```